# PHP routing help needed

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes

My `.htaccess` file is like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

And my `index.php`:

```php
echo '<pre>';
print_r(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
echo '</pre>';
```

When I go to `example.com/test/one/two`, it gives me back:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => test
    [2] => one
    [3] => two
)
```

Why is there a 0?

Answer (score 1):

Because your `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is `/test/one/two`.

To get rid of that you could remove first slash from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

```
substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
```

Comment: But why in the array is there a 0. I know arrays starts with a 0. Why is 'test' not the beginning of the array?

Comment: Because there is an empty string in front of the first slash

Comment: explode function splits string on boundary formed by delimiter parameter. So when you have your delimiter as first character in string it puts an empty string into a resulting array.